# Switching temperature of two objects

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Say you have two physically congruent blocks A and A 1kg each. A has an initial temperature of 100 degrees celsius, and B has a temperature of 0. Through whatever cutting and manipulating the blocks you want, is it possible to make block B 100 degrees and block A 0 degrees through merely conducting heat through touching parts of the blocks that you cut?

Keep in mind that all dissassembled parts of each block must be reconstructed to the original block, and cannot be mixed.

My goal is to make the reconstructed B block, after whatever manipulation, 100 degrees and A, 0 degrees. Temperature is conducted based on mass, for instance if you touch a 0.3kg part of the red block with a 0.1 kg part of the blue block, both will be 75 degrees. The temperature equilibriates instantly based on mass and there is no heat loss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quite an interesting thermodynamics riddle!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522400/quite-an-interesting-thermodynamics-riddle)

Comment: No, @JMac. I have done some casework on the case that both the blocks are split in two. Now we have two A blocks half the original size at 100 degrees each, and two congruent B blocks at 0 degrees each. If we combine one of the A blocks with a B block we get the following: A [100,50]; B[50,0]. If we repeat the process with the 50 degree A block we get A[100, 25]; B[50, 25]; Now that we only have one A block left that can possibly raise the B block temperature, we get A[50,25], B[75,50]. Combine and we get A [37.5] and B[62.5]. B-A=25

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. The blocks are already at the greatest temperature difference. Once the two blocks reach equilibrium at the mid point, no further heat transference is possible. Heat can only move from a warmer to a colder environment.

Answer (score 0):

No, that violates the Clausius formulation of the Second Law of Thermodynamics:

*There is no thermodynamic process whose sole effect it to transfer heat from a body at a lower temperature to one at a higher temperature.*

Comment: Well, @Buzz I have done some casework on the case that both the blocks are split in two. Now we have two A blocks half the original size at 100 degrees each, and two congruent B blocks at 0 degrees each. If we combine one of the A blocks with a B block we get the following: A [100,50]; B[50,0]. If we repeat the process with the 50 degree A block we get A[100, 25]; B[50, 25]; Now that we only have one A block left that can possibly raise the B block temperature, we get A[50,25], B[75,50]. Combine and we get A [37.5] and B[62.5]. B-A=25.  I wrote some code, and if we keep doing the same process

Comment: , but split the blocks infinitely, we near but evidently never achieve a total swap. With 2 splits, we get a difference of 25, and the data as follows.
4 45.3125
8 60.7239
16 72.01
32 80.1306
64 85.9228
128 90.0362
256 92.9511
512 95.0144
1024 96.4742
2048 97.5068
4096 98.237
8192 98.7533
16384 99.1185

Comment: The answer is still no.